# Jquery Validator not working in IE 7 or 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I have a large multi-directional form that validates almost all fields with Jquery Validator, including several custom function.  It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, but not IE 7 or 8.  I am sure there it is just something trivial and I am going bald trying to figure it out!  Any help is greatly appreciated. Staging site can be viewed at:

http://173.45.237.55/qrf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery Validator doesn't work with jQuery 1.6 in IE at this time.  You're including jquery-latest.js, which is 1.6.  Include 1.5.2 specifically and it should work just fine.

Comment: Validator 1.8 Works with Jquery 1.6