# jQuery Validate causing error in IE 7 & 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Using jQuery 1.5.2 getting javascript error:

```
Error: '$.validator.methods[...]' is null or not an object
```

I have tested it in IE7 and IE8 and got the error. The validation works fine in Firefox 4 and earlier.

When tabbing from the address1 field to address2 field.. in fact when clicking from address1 with info in it to addres2 with no info. Also... weird when tabbing or clicking from the Zip field to the county field I get no error with info in or out of zip and/or county... also, the zip field has a maskedinput validation on it county does not. I was using jQuery 1.4.2 and saw this response to a similar question 
   ([Jquery Validator not working in IE 7 or 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957521/jquery-validator-not-working-in-ie-7-or-8)).
I was using jQuery 1.4.2 and upped to 1.5.2 with the same results.

Here is my validate code.

```
$('#frm_subefoLocation').validate({
  rules: {
    address1: { require:true,maxlength:100,minlength:2},
    address2: { require:false,maxlength:100},
    city: { require:true,maxlength:100,minlength:2},
    zip: { required:true,minlength:5,maxlength:10,number:true},
    county: { require:false,maxlength:100,minlength:0},
    mailAddress1: { require:true,maxlength:100,minlength:2},
    mailAddress2: { require:false,maxlength:100,minlength:0},
    mailCity: { require:true,maxlength:100,minlength:2},
    mailZip: { required:true,minlength:5,maxlength:10,number:true}
  }
});
```

Here is the masked input code:

```
// set up mask for entry
$('#zip').mask('99999');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Formatting your code properly will help people want to answer you.

Comment: Hey @Chris I went ahead and formatted your code up. You may want to include a link to the validate plugin you are using. You might also want to try a whack at validating with the h5validate plugin which is more future oriented.

Comment: Gabriel, thanks for the formatting... tried to find the formatting tags, but didn't... I hope someone knows a fix... this is rampant all over a huge reporting site... will change if needed, but..  :|

Comment: Oops.. here is the plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: and... $Id: jquery.validate.js 6403 2009-06-17 14:27:16Z joern.zaefferer $

Comment: The masked input plugin is this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license
Version: 1.2.2 (03/09/2009 22:39:06)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code this morning I noticed...   'require' is not allowed... 'required' is required..
The difference didn't bother Firefox but sure did mess with IE.